# Is there a package in R that lets me make a graphic table in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a NBA app on Shiny, and right now I'm trying to make a search engine that shows you a player's stats. This is what it looks like right now.
[image]
However, I was wondering if there was any package that lets me spruce it up. For example, I'd like to add a background, add relevant info beside the image, and then have stats below. The ESPN and NBA ones are good examples.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362) and show your efforts so far.  To build such an app in shiny you will have to ppush it to its limits, I guess

Comment: Try shinydashboard. Then use the `box` function to wrap things in boxes to control the layout

Comment: @MEDWITT shinydashboard is the way to go

Comment: Look at shinydashboardplus as well for pre-built options. To do above, you would have to create all custom functions in HTML/CSS.